# Access array elements task

Tags: javascript

Here is my task:

A lookUpProfile function that takes name and a property (prop) as arguments has been pre-written for you.

1. The function should check if name is an actual contact's firstName and the given property (prop) is a property of that contact.
2. If both are true, then return the "value" of that property.
3. If name does not correspond to any contacts then return "No such contact"
4. If prop does not correspond to any valid properties of a contact found to match name then return "No such property"

Paragraphs 3,4 are executed well, please tell me why my paragraphs 1,2 are not working.

Here is the code:

```
    //Setup
    var contacts = [
        {
            "firstName": "Akira",
            "lastName": "Laine",
            "number": "0543236543",
            "likes": ["Pizza", "Coding", "Brownie Points"]
        },
        {
            "firstName": "Harry",
            "lastName": "Potter",
            "number": "0994372684",
            "likes": ["Hogwarts", "Magic", "Hagrid"]
        },
        {
            "firstName": "Sherlock",
            "lastName": "Holmes",
            "number": "0487345643",
            "likes": ["Intriguing Cases", "Violin"]
        },
        {
            "firstName": "Kristian",
            "lastName": "Vos",
            "number": "unknown",
            "likes": ["JavaScript", "Gaming", "Foxes"]
        }
    ];


    function lookUpProfile(name, prop){
    // Only change code below this line
    for (var i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++) {
      if (name === contacts[i].firstName) {
        if (prop === contacts[i][prop]) {
          return contacts[i][prop];
        } else {
          return "No such property";
        }
      } else {
        return "No such contact";
      }
    }
    // Only change code above this line
    }






    }
    // Change these values to test 

your function
lookUpProfile("Akira", "likes");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 problems in your code:

1. It always returns after the first contact, no matter whether it matches or not
2. It compares the string prop (`'likes'`) against the value (some array), which will never be true.

x

```
function lookUpProfile(name, prop) {
    for (var i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++) {
        if (name === contacts[i].firstName) {
            if (contacts[i][prop]) {
                return contacts[i][prop];
            } else {
                return "No such property";
            }
        }
    }
    return "No such contact";
}
```

Comment: Probably the problem is in "return"

Comment: Say it "doesn't work" isn't helpful. You need to explain what is happening and what you expect to happen: https://jsfiddle.net/3rweoabq/

Comment: "Kristian", "lastName" should return "Vos"/
"Sherlock", "likes" should return ["Intriguing Cases", "Violin"]

but nothing is returning

Comment: wrong values, return the correct variant: "No such property" or "No such contact"